# Targeting select option with CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to target the selected option in this select tag. Is there a ::selected psuedo class that I can use to manipulate it?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" id="category">
        <option disabled selected>Gifts by category</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to select it with the attribute selector. Like this:

`#category option[selected] { /*styles*/ }`

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yr03pezw/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't style the option.

You can use this css to remove the default styles for the select itself though...

See snippet:

```css
.select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<select class="select">
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
  <option>D</option>
  <option>E</option>
  <option>F</option>
</select>
```

Or you can use one of these: https://codepen.io/ericrasch/pen/zjDBx